# Implicit CALayer animation does not animate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation

I am trying to animate sliding out one view from a window and simultaneous sliding in another. Like so:

```
     Window
------------------  
|----------------| ------------------
||              || |                |
||     view     || |      view      |
||  sliding out || |   sliding in   |
|----------------| ------------------
------------------  
      <---                <---
```

I'm using layer backed views, trying to use implicit animation and a CATransaction. What's happening is that the view sliding out animates, but the one sliding in, just jumps into place. Here's my code:

```
    NSView *slidingInView = nil;
    NSView *slidingOutView = nil;
    if (currentState.primaryView != nextState.primaryView) {
        // Slide in a primary view
        [self.window.contentView addSubview:nextState.primaryView];
        CGRect frame = nextState.primaryView.layer.frame; 
        frame.origin.x = slideFromRight ? frame.size.width : 0 - frame.size.width;
        [nextState.primaryView.layer setPosition: frame.origin];

        slidingInView = nextState.primaryView;
        slidingOutView = currentState.primaryView;
    }

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]
                     forKey:kCATransactionAnimationTimingFunction];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [slidingOutView removeFromSuperview];
    }];

    // Slide in the new view
    slidingInView.layer.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

    // if there is a view in place already, slide it out to the left.
    if (slidingOutView != nil) {

        CGRect frame = slidingOutView.layer.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(slidingOutView.layer.frame.size.width, slidingOutView.layer.frame.origin.y);
        if (slideRight)
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(0-slidingOutView.layer.frame.size.width, slidingOutView.layer.frame.origin.y);

        [slidingOutView.layer setPosition: frame.origin];
    }

    [CATransaction commit];
```

This is a complete mystery to me. Does anyone have a clue? My window's contentView has setWantsLayer: YES, as has all the views I'm sliding in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit animations only work for *standalone* layers (layer that are not backing up a view).

You need to explicitly animate the layer (and change the property value since it doesn't happen by default). It would look something like

```
CABasicAnimation *slideIn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[slideIn setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myNewEndPoint]];
[slideIn setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[[slidingInView layer] position]]];
[[slidingInView layer] addAnimation:slideIn forKey:@"mySlideInAnimation"];
[[slidingInView layer] setPosition:myNewEndPoint];
```

---

Also: unless you have changed the anchor point, the position of the layer should be in the center (which means that setting it to (0,0) will make 3/4 of the layer appear off-screen

Comment: Excellent! That's just what the doctor ordered. I really liked the simplicity of implicit animations, but this works. ;) By the way, valueWithCGPoint is not defined on the Mac, so I'm using valueWithPoint which takes an NSPoint, so I need to cast, which is kind of ugly. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'm so used to iOS that I forgot that there was a difference with NSValue